# How to retrieve innerHTML of the page using Angular2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, typescript

I have 2 questions as follow:

1) I am migrating the UI of an application from jQuery to Angular2. There is a feature that the user can modify the UI layout through drag & drop and re-sizing of html div elements. The user can also add new divs/ sections in the page.

While, storing the data, I was looping through all the child elements, preparing a JSON array holding all child elements as well as CSS attributes. While loading the page back, I was again looping through the array and appending the elements and setting attributes. It was quite easy job to achieve using jQuery.

Now, with Angular2, I am having difficulties achieving the same. I can bind the [innerHTML] with the div, however, the challenge I am having is to retrieve the inner html of the page.

Any suggestion will be appreciated!!

2) Is there a better way to store the page layout and parse back while loading?

Thanks!!

Comment: I also explored the option of using ViewChild decorator, however, did not find anything to get the inner html elements with the attribute values.

Comment: Show your code! You dont need innerHtml. You can do everything using components!

Comment: Just do #ref on placeholder.. then in ts @ViewChild('ref') el: Element; Then you can do el.innerHTML to get it.. You should be trying to drop jQuery approach though..